# While toggle, show/ hide numeric key pad changed to alpha-numeric keypad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In mobile, when inserted pin number, and then toggle show/hide then numeric key pad also changed to alphanumeric keypad.
I required, when I toggle show/hide button it should be only display numeric keypad

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input type="{{inputType}}" placeholder="Put your pin" inputmode="numeric" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" ng-model="passwordCheckbox" ng-click="hideShow()" />
  <label for="checkbox" ng-if="passwordCheckbox">Hide Pin</label>
  <label for="checkbox" ng-if="!passwordCheckbox">Show Pin</label>  
</section>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and js file is

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function( $scope ){
  
  // Set the default value of inputType
  $scope.inputType = 'password';
  
  // Hide & show pin function
  $scope.hideShow = function(){
    if ($scope.inputType == 'password')
      $scope.inputType = 'text';
    else
      $scope.inputType = 'password';
  };
  
}]);
```

and css

```
section {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin: 3em auto;
  padding: 2em;
  width: 600px;
}
input {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

1. when entering pin it shows numeric keypad
2. when toggle show numeric keypad change to alphanumeric keypad

how to show only numeric key pad while toggling button?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the text input type to be `number` instead of text.

```
  // Hide & show pin function
  $scope.hideShow = function(){
    $scope.inputType = $scope.inputType == 'password' ? 'number' : 'password';
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay.. but still have the same issue

Comment: have you tried also toggling the `inputmode="numeric"`? I am not familiar with that attribute...